# Determine whether a number is a power of 3

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Why does $\frac{\log(n)}{\log(3)}$ being an integer determine whether $n$ is a power of three?

While doing some programming exercises I came across this problem and the above formula was a proposed solution. Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: The answers you received are correct mathematically, but this formula is a bit dangerous in programming.  Checking whether the ratio of two floats is an integer requires some care.  Neither of the logs is exact in the computer.

Comment: To underscore @RossMillikan's point, the difference between the logs of $3^{20}$ (close to MAXINT in $32$ bits) and $3^{20}-1$ is on the order of one part in $10^{11}$ (so you would need a double-precision float in order to capture this difference).

Comment: Assuming $n$ is a positive integer, it's better to simply do integer division by $3$ until one either has a remainder or ends up at $1$.  In the former case, the number is not a power of $3$; in the latter case, it is.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $\frac{\ln n}{\ln 3}=k$ with $k$ being an integer.

Then $\ln n=k\ln 3=\ln 3^k$ and so $n=3^k$

Comment: It doesn't significantly affect the validity of your answer, but the OP is using $\lg n \equiv \log_2 n$, not $\ln n$.

Comment: Given $log_b x = \frac {\log_c x}{\log_c b}$ then $\log_3 x =\lg x/\lg 3 = \ln x/\ln 3 = \log_{anything} x /\log_{anything} 3$ it doesn't matter which base one uses. ... but then, again, maybe this fact isn't known by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Because $n = 3^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ iff $k = \log_3 n = \frac{\lg n}{\lg 3} \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change of base formula for logarithms : $$\log_b(x)=\frac{\log_d(x)}{\log_d(b)}$$Also note the following formula to relate logs to exponents:$$\log_b(b^x) = x$$ this since for any base $b$, $\log_3(n)=\frac{\log_b(n)}{\log_b(3)}$, and and power of $3$ will be of the form $3^x$, we have:$$\frac{\log(3^x)}{\log(3)}=\log_3(3^x)=x$$

Therefore, if $n$ is put into the formula, you will recieve a number $x$ such that $n=3^x$. If $x$ is an integer, then you know that $n$ is a power of $3$.